# Native code execution by JVM/CLR

Tags: clr, jvm, jit

How does JVM/CLR execute JIT compiled native code? Is it by some code injection or by copying code to executable memory? What are the system calls that allows dynamic code execution?

Answer (score 3):

I can explain how we do it in [CACAO VM](http://cacaojvm.org/) (a research JIT-only JVM). First, the machine code for a method is generated into some heap-allocated memory block. After compilation, the final code length is known, and a chunk of executable memory is allocated using `mmap` and the `PROT_EXEC` flag (relevant CACAO code [here](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/hg/cacao/file/64ad75e2087e/src/mm/codememory.c#l121)). Then, the machine code is copied into the mmapped area. After that, many architectures require some machine-specific cache flushing mechanism. As an example, have a look at the [cache-flushing function](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/hg/cacao/file/64ad75e2087e/src/vm/jit/powerpc64/asmpart.S#l403) for PowerPC 64. Notably, on i386 and x86_64, there is nothing to do. After this step, the processor is ready to execute the newly-generated code. Alternatively, already allocated memory pages can be marked executable with `mprotect`. Note that `mmap`/`mprotect` are Unix facilities.

Comment: Considering DEP and the clear separation of data and executable code and that executable memory cannot be written to and data memory cannot be jumped/executed to, I'd be still very interested in how it's done on Win32 systems with CLR/JIT.

Comment: @Abel You may find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/21/dynamicbase-and-nxcompat.aspx) article interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically how Java does it, but in general you'd insert "trap" opcodes into the interpreter's instruction stream. There are two opcodes [in the JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions.doc.html#60105) that seem tailor-made for this purpose.

If you want to know for sure, there's no better answer than the source: http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

Answer (score 2):

The Common Language Runtime has a methodtable for each type with entries pointing to native code or a native stub to JIT managed code and then fixup the methodtable with the pointer to the just created native code.

MSDN has a more in depth [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects) in the MethodDesc section

[This blog entry by Dave Notario](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924010928/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/10/26/247792.aspx) explains how the CLR JIT compiler works.